# Fill int array with data from cursor?

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, cursor, gallery

im trying to populate an int array from a cursor of sqlite database.I want to set a gallery view with some photos but my code doesnt work:

```
String uri = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(HipotecaDbAdapter.C_COLUMNA_FOTO1));
          int Idfoto = this.getResources().getIdentifier(uri,null,this.getPackageName());

         imgsimple.setImageResource(Idfoto);
```

C_COLUMNA_FOTO1 have an string :'R.drawable.foto1,R.drawable.foto2'

Any ideas?

Comment: Feel free to explain what "doesn't work" means for you.

Comment: @user3136374 What is your actual issue ?

Comment: I have a cursor from an sqlite database that contains the path of images saved in res/drawables. I want to show this photos in a gallery or imageswitcher but i dont know how to obtain this data from cursor and populate the necessary array of my gallery.It works with 1 photo,but not with more....